# Multipart Upload not working in QObject moved to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm trying to upload an image to my webserver using MultiPart in Qt. When I run the code below from my MainWindow through a button, it works fine.

When I try to implement the exact code in a class inheriting from QObject that's being moved to a thread, it does not reach te SIGNAL/SLOT and no file is uploaded.

Could anyone please point out where my mistake is? Been on this for a while without any positive outcome.

Thanks!

Implementation of the thread/worker class

```
#include "screenshotworker.h"
#include "session.h"
#include "json.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QApplication>


ScreenshotWorker::ScreenshotWorker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void ScreenshotWorker::DoSetup(QThread *cThread, Session *aSession)
{
   session = aSession;
   connect(cThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(DoWork()));
}

void ScreenshotWorker::DoWork()
{

    while(session->sessActive)
    {

        QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

        QHttpPart textPart;
        textPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"session\""));
        textPart.setBody(QByteArray::number(session->session_id));

        QHttpPart imagePart;
        imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("image/png"));
        imagePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"screen.png\""));
        QFile *file = new QFile("screen.png");
        file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        imagePart.setBodyDevice(file);
        file->setParent(multiPart); // we cannot delete the file now, so delete it with the multiPart

        multiPart->append(textPart);
        multiPart->append(imagePart);

        QUrl url("http://........");
        QNetworkRequest request(url);

        QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
        reply = manager->post(request, multiPart);
        multiPart->setParent(reply); // delete the multiPart with the reply


        connect(reply, SIGNAL( uploadProgress(qint64, qint64) ), this, SLOT( uploadProgress(qint64,qint64) ) ) ;
        connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(uploadDone()));

        sleep(10);
     }
}

void ScreenshotWorker::uploadProgress(qint64 bytesSent, qint64 bytesTotal) {
    qDebug() << "Uploaded" << bytesSent << "of" << bytesTotal;
}

void ScreenshotWorker::uploadDone() {
    qDebug() << "Finished" << reply->errorString() <<reply->attribute( QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
    qDebug()<<reply->readAll();

    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Calling this on a button press, starting the thread.

```
QThread *cThread2 = new QThread();
ScreenshotWorker *cWorker2 = new ScreenshotWorker();

cWorker2->DoSetup(cThread2, mSession);
cWorker2->moveToThread(cThread2);
cThread2->start();
```

Comment: That `reply->deleteLater()` looks suspicious. Are you sure that's intended?

Comment: @kfunk That ended up there with copy pasting into StackOverflow. It's still the same though. I updated the post with the code implementation for the thread worker class.

Comment: Are you creating and launching the `EventLoop` in the `cThread2`?

Comment: Try moving the worker to the thread before connecting signals/doing setup

Comment: EventLoop was indeed not created and launched. I have added this and everything works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments above, I was able to resolve this by adding the event loop.

```
QEventLoop loop;        
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()),&loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();
```